# PHP Arrays duplicating?

Tags: php, database, arrays, foreach

I am trying to code a cron job so if a code in the database and is unused and older then 72 hours it drops the row in the database.

The problem I am having however is that when I am trying to get the array data in a row, so I can run an 'If statement' and then the drop command, when printing the array I get duplicates like as follows

```
33520891520891do not usedo not use----aaron hattonaaron hattonSunday 8th of September 2013 12:46:20 PMSunday 8th of September 2013 12:46:20 PMUnusedUnused--
```

My code is as follows

```
// Set variable for the time
$timenow = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    // Start Expired password check and drop function
    function cronexec_expired ($timenow) {

        include('../../config.php');

        // Open up a new MySQLi connection to the MySQL database
        mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
        mysql_select_db($dbTable);

        // Query to check the status of the code input
        $expiry_check = "SELECT * FROM code_log WHERE status='Unused'";

        // Run the query
        $expiry_checkexec = mysql_query($expiry_check);

        while($expiry_possibles = mysql_fetch_array($expiry_checkexec)) {

            foreach ($expiry_possibles as $expiry_possible) {

                print_r ($expiry_possible);

            };

        }


    }

    // Start Redeemed Password check and drop function

// Execute Functions
cronexec_expired ($timenow);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

**Edit**

When removing the 'foreach' and running the following:

```
print_r ($expiry_possibles);
```

I get the following

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [id] => 3 [1] => 520891 [code] => 520891 [2] => do not use [refid] => do not use [3] => - [hostname] => - [4] => - [userip] => - [5] => aaron hatton [creater] => aaron hatton [6] => Sunday 8th of September 2013 12:46:20 PM [timecreated] => Sunday 8th of September 2013 12:46:20 PM [7] => Unused [status] => Unused [8] => - [timeredeemed] => - )
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you mean numeric index in your array output. use mysql_fetch_assoc() instead of mysql_fetch_array()

mysql_fetch_array() essentially returns two arrays one with numeric index, one with associative string index.

Comment: the issue is not the MySQL Query as when run in phpMyAdmin it only shows one row, the issue is the data when put into an array and printed (print_r) duplicates itself as per the example

Comment: remove foreach loop and print_r data!!

Comment: you mean numeric indexes ? user mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array . :)